# Update node properties AEM using custom workflow

Tags: java, aem

I was trying to update the metadata of DAM Asset adding a new property-value using custom workflow. The below code works fine in the execute() method.

```
 Resource metadata = resourceResolver.getResource(resourcePath);
        ModifiableValueMap properties = metadata.adaptTo(ModifiableValueMap.class);
        properties.put("360 degree", "true");

        try {
            metadata.getResourceResolver().commit();
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Updating the code as below the property-value is not being created.

```
  Resource metadata = resourceResolver.getResource(resourcePath);  
  Node metanode = metadata.adaptTo(Node.class);
        try {
            metanode.setProperty("360 degree", "true", PropertyType.BOOLEAN);
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you forget to call `javax.jcr.Session#save`.

But you should not use the JCR api when working in AEM, rely on the Sling API or even higher level apis (wcm in particular) if possible.